# Move a button from point A to point B using XAML/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Generally speaking what's the way to move (animate, transform, whatever words; no matter) a `button` from `point A` (by user click as a source) to `point B` (by user click as a target) in `C#/XAML`? (Imagine a board game such as like Chess in order to move a piece from `A` to `B`).

I'm working on a project with the following specifications:

My methodology is `MVVM`: so I've created a `custom button` (derived from `ButtonBase`) to simulate a piece which is assigned by a `delegate command` (to move) for each cell in a grid as well as `dependency properties` and `INotification` for events. Not to mentions that I've never used from `Canvas` and `Panel` in this case. I also used from `StoryBoard` which is called from within `dependency object` to trigger the animation.

Having said that I'm looking for a way to move a `button` from `A` to `B` by user click.  Keep in mind I know about `Transform` to move an object however how could be it possible to specify a `source` (by first click) and then specify the `To` to target (by next click) and how to manage the back and forth events?

Comment: What about using drag and drop? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `My methodology is MVVM: so I've created a custom button` - What??

Answer (score 0):

For any kind of animations keeping `MVVM` concept clear you should use `Storyboards` and `Animations`. And if you really want to move your button in space - use `Canvas`. Within `Canvas` you can create awesome animations.
Simple example:

```
<Canvas>
    <Button Canvas.Left="1" Width="100" Height="100" Content="Flying button..">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation                                
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                        From="1.0" To="100.0" Duration="0:0:5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Canvas>
```

And result:

[image]